# Send flutter A_page data to B,C,D,E

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

If I press ElevatedButton on the flutter A_page, I switch the screen with the data on the A_page to B_page

A_page code

```
SizedBox(
                                    width: 200,
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                      child: Text('Profile_Edit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),),
                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.teal, side: BorderSide.none, shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: (){
                                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context){
                                              return B_page(data:data);
                                            }
                                        ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

What I want is to send the data of A_page to C, D, and E
However, the screen switch must only be B_page

C, D and E have DropdownButton

However, the problem here is that C, D, and E contain final function (string value) on Selected; so you have to write the code in the form below

```
C_controller(
                      onSelected: (String value){
                        c_value = value;
                      },
                    ),
```

I can't solve this Can someone help me?

I acted as follows to solve this
Failed to do something like Navigator.push or Navigator.pushName onPressed

Comment: can you share the minimal code

Comment: Why do you want to send data to the pages that are not visible?

Comment: I think you want to achieve update value on one page and update them on other pages is it right ? If right then use ValueNotifier to make that

Comment: A_page is profile_page and B_page is profile_edit_page.
And C, D, E are the dropdown Buttons in the profile_edit_page